# How would I use regex to check for a value that has two fixed uppercase letters followed by numeric values in PHP or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, regex

An example would be "SU1203" or "UP1234" or any two letters followed by numeric values.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with the quite simple expression

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d+$
```

In JavaScript you can use the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```
if(/^[A-Z]{2}\d+$/.test(str))
```

and in PHP, [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}\d+$/', $str) === 1)
```

I suggest to [**learn regular expressions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

See also:

- [Regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [Regular expressions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (preg_match('|^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]+$|', $string_to_test))
{
  // matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript example:

```
if ( /(^[A-Z]{2}\d+)/.test('SU1203') ) {
   alert( 'matched' )
} else { alert('not matched') }
```